# Add my own login to Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership, umbraco7

Im using Umbraco 7 and would like to integrate my own systems login facility into Umbraco 7 (WinForms not MVC) but at the same time use the current Umbraco login facility to allow admin staff to login as usual into Umbraco and make changes.

When i say own system i mean a website created by us which contains user accounts, when they registered (this was built using .Net 2.0).

I've searched Umbraco and so all seems tightly integrated and wondered if anyone has a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to customize Umbraco's built-in MemberShip, read more about that here: http://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2015/extending-membership/

All though, by the sound of your question, you're wanting to make changes to the Users in Umbraco rather than the Members.

As far as I'm concerned, "Users" are quite tightly integrated into Umbraco, all though, there is the UserService you can play around with. Read more on that here: http://programystic.com/code/umbraco/create-a-new-umbraco-user-programmatically-on-startup-when-locked-out/

You could technically ensure your WinForms users are always in sync with your Umbraco users. When updates are made to your WinForms users, make sure WinForms call up to an API on your Umbraco site that syncs the data with the Umbraco user.

This might not be the ideal solution, but it could work as a workaround.

Comment: I will look into those links. What i would like to do is use our own implementation of the logging in system for external users and for internal users use Umbracos. In short im trying to integrate two systems into one

Answer (score 0):

I programmed a ActiveDirectory solution, changed:  Umbraco.Web\Security\WebSecurity.cs, you can use whatever you get in from your host. I use ActiveDirectory authentication. I developed an HybridMembershipProvider for both members and users. Its Umbraco 7.5.5., for ActiveDirectory you need to change the checking of password in the provider, because the password checking in ActiveDirectory is delegated to Windows.

```
/// <summary>
/// Ensures that a back office user is logged in
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;

    if (_httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // user is already authenticated in umbraco.
        if (_httpContext.GetCurrentIdentity(false) != null)
            isAuthenticated = true;

        // check user in umbraco, and if found set as authenticated.
        else
        {
            // active directory username.
            var userName = _httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Replace("MOD\\", string.Empty);
            var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, string.Empty, isPersistent: true, shouldLockout: true).Result;
            if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                // log this user in backoffice.
                var user = GetBackOfficeUser(_httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Replace("MOD\\", string.Empty));
                PerformLogin(user.Id);

                // and set as authenticated.
                isAuthenticated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //return _httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && _httpContext.GetCurrentIdentity(false) != null;
    return isAuthenticated;
}
```

Comment: I dont seem to have access to  Umbraco.Web\Security\WebSecurity.cs - where do you get access to this file? I noticed your code return _httpContext.User.Identity but i want to override this and use my own implementation (perhaps by overriding the global.asax file)